# Resharper pattern to detect arithmetic with nullable types

Tags: c#, resharper

Can anyone think of good Resharper pattern that will detect the following bug:

```
decimal? x = null;

decimal? y = 6M;

var total = x + y;

Console.WriteLine(total); // Result is null
```

I've tried creating a pattern but I can't work out how to quickly handle all types of arithmetic (e.g. +, -, * etc), and any nullable type (`e.g. Nullable<int>, Nullable<decimal>, Nullable<double> etc`). Also I can't handle commutativity (e.g. it should detect *x + y* as well as *y + x*).

Note that I don't necessarily need to detect whether or not *x* is actually null: just whether or not it is a nullable type. I want to force developers to write: x.Value + y.Value.

Comment: erm nullable is just a generic class.
Nullable<T> Structure
why not just make this pattern thingy on: "Nullable<T>"

Comment: And don't check for an `x + y` pattern, but look for a `Nullable<T>` that has been surely assigned with `null` and not has any of `+`,`-`,`*`,`/`,`^`,`*`,`~`,`<<`,`>>` in either left or right of it (or `-=`,`+=`,... on it's left).

Comment: @cbp Worst case scenario - you copy-paste the pattern for each arithmetic-supporting type. Though you won't consider other types that overrode those operators... So yeah, you're gonna need to generalize that. Why doesn't it work with `Nullable<T>`?

Comment: @yorye Yes that is definitely worst case - there are many types that support arithmetic operations, and unless I can support commutativity the number of different copy-and-pasted versions of the pattern are going to increase rapidly.

Comment: @yorye I'm not sure I understand what you are saying - could you give an example of the pattern.

Comment: Sadly, no... I haven't really tried making any patterns of my own for ReSharper, so I have no experience with it. I was just throwing out ideas, hoping you or someone else make good use out of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a full answer, but this is the best I've come up with so far.

The pattern is:

```
$obj$ + $nullableObj$
```

**obj** is an "*expression of type System.Object or one of its derived types*
**nullableObj** is an "*expression of type System.Nullable*". (Note that you don't want nullableObj to include derived types).

This not a very good solution because the pattern doesn't handle commutativity, so you'll need to copy and paste it and reverse the expressions:

```
$nullableObj$ + $obj$
```

Also, this pattern only handles decimal, so you'll need to copy and paste it for each type that you interested in (yes, that's potentially a lot of patterns).

One piece of good news: The *+* symbol handles both addition and subtraction, so you don't need to worry about subtraction.